# My JComboBox displays blank entry when I made a range of array

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm trying to make a JComboBox GUI that displays years. I expect the combo box to start at 1910 but the GUI shows a blank entry and you could only see the items when you scroll down, although the console starts at 1910. I don't know if there's something wrong in my combo box or in my for-loop. Is there any way to fix this? Beginner here :)

```
Integer[] year = new Integer[2020];

for(int i = 1910; i < year.length; i++) {
    year[i] = i;
    //System.out.println(year[i]);
}
yearBox = new JComboBox(year);
```

[image]

Comment: Use an array of length that you need, not of length 2020.

Comment: `int[] year = new int[2020 - 1910];` Or better yet, use a `Vector<Integer>`

Comment: You have 110 `null` elements, see the other comments from above, but essentially your array is to big for your use case.  Personally, I'd use my own `ComboBoxModel`, but that's me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the GUI shows a blank entry and you could only see the items when you scroll down

Because you have 1909 empty values in your Array, since you only add values starting at 1910.

```
for(int i = 1910; i < year.length; i++) {
    
    year[i] = i;
    //System.out.println(year[i]);
    
    
}
```

Why are you creating an Array?

Just add the Items directly to the combo box:

```
yearBox = new JComboBox();
for(int i = 1910; i < year.length; i++) {
    yearBox.addItem( Integer.valueOf(i) );
    //System.out.println(year[i]);
}
```